# Lua - calls only one operator in metatable

Tags: lua, operators, metatable

I'm new to Lua, so maybe missed something on tutorials but the problem is:

I have original table and metatable with several operators that I'm applying to it:

```
original = { 1, 2, 3 }

test = setmetatable(original, {
  __add = function (lhs, rhs)
    print('adds')
  end,
  __mul = function (lhs, rhs)
    print('multiplies')
  end  
})
```

Unfortunately when I'm doing operations like:

```
test = test + 3
test = test * 3
```

I receive an error:

```
attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'test' (a table value)
```

Didn't find any descriptions on this problem. Also I *noticed* that if metatable is a separate variable and passed to `setmetatable` method then it works..

Comment: Your code example works for me. Is there something you're not including? What is that global `multiplies` in your error?

Comment: sorry, it's just a typo, global is ``test`` of course, I'm using Lua 5.1

Comment: yeah, it worked for me too now in a separate file, seems like my fault..

Comment: I updated my question with correct values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error I get is

> attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'test' (a nil value)

This means that `test` is nil in the last line. You need to return something in `__add`.

Comment: This error makes much more sense than the original message, which suggested that the table `test` didn't have the proper arithmetic metamethods.

Answer (score 5):

```
test = test + 3
```

Is loosely equivalent to:

```
test = getmetatable(test).__add(test, 3)
```

You're assigning the return value of `__add` to `test`.

`_add` returns nothing, so after the first line, `test` is `nil`.  Then you do it again:

```
test = getmetatable(test).__add(test, 3)
```

You can't index or get the metatable of `nil`.

---

An easy what to have discovered this, probably the first thing I would have tried:

```
test = test + 3
print(test)
test = test * 3
```